# C: malloc of string showing unexpected behaviour with double pointer and function calls

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, double-pointer

This is a query to understand how the below code is working fine even with a mistake.

As per my knowledge, if I want to reallocate/ re-assign a pointer passed to a function, that pointer needs to be passed as a double pointer. By mistake, I passed a single pointer and the program is still working. I guess it has to do something with the pointer being a string.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func2( char **x){

    printf("befor func2 x = %u; *x = %u; **x = %s; x_size = %u\n", x, *x, *x, strlen(*x));
    free(*x);
    *x = (char *)malloc(20);
    strcpy(*x, "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih");

    printf("\n\nafter func2 x = %u; *x = %u; **x = %s; x_size = %u\n", x, *x, *x, strlen(*x));
}

void func1( char *x){

    printf("befor func1 &x = %u; x = %u; *x = %s; x_size = %u \n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
    func2(&x);
    printf("after func1 &x = %u; x = %u; *x = %s; x_size = %u \n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
}

int main(){

    char *x; 
    x = (char *)malloc(10);
    strcpy(x, "abcdefghi");
    printf("befor  main &x = %u; x = %u; x = %s; x_size = %u\n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
    func1(x);
    printf("after  main &x = %u; x = %u; x = %s; x_size = %u\n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
    free(x);
    return 1;
}
```

OutPut:

```
befor  main &x = 489275896; x = 20414480; x = abcdefghi; x_size = 9
befor func1 &x = 489275864; x = 20414480; *x = abcdefghi; x_size = 9 
befor func2 x = 489275864; *x = 20414480; **x = abcdefghi; x_size = 9


after func2 x = 489275864; *x = 20414480; **x = zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih; x_size = 19
after func1 &x = 489275864; x = 20414480; *x = zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih; x_size = 19 
after  main &x = 489275896; x = 20414480; x = zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih; x_size = 19
```

I can understand the output till `func1`. But how the size and values are getting returned to `main` after being modified in `func2`? I've not passed `x` as a double pointer from `main` to `func1`. But somehow it's still working.

Is it because it is a `char *`?

**Edit 1:**

After suggested edits in the comments:

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func2( char **x){

    printf("befor func2 x = %p; *x = %p; **x = %s; x_size = %u\n", x, *x, *x, strlen(*x));
    free(*x);
    *x = (char *)malloc(20);
    strcpy(*x, "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih");

    printf("\n\nafter func2 x = %p; *x = %p; **x = %s; x_size = %u\n", x, *x, *x, strlen(*x));
}

void func1( char *x){

    printf("befor func1 &x = %p; x = %p; *x = %s; x_size = %u \n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
    func2(&x);
    printf("after func1 &x = %p; x = %p; *x = %s; x_size = %u \n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
}

int main(){

    char *x, *y, *z; 
    x = (char *)malloc(10);
    z = (char *)malloc(100);
    y = (char *)malloc(100);
    strcpy(x, "abcdefghi");
    printf("befor  main &x = %p; x = %p; x = %s; x_size = %u\n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
    func1(x);
    printf("after  main &x = %p; x = %p; x = %s; x_size = %u\n", &x, x, x, strlen(x));
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
befor  main &x = 0x7fff78cb09c8; x = 0x1c7a010; x = abcdefghi; x_size = 9
befor func1 &x = 0x7fff78cb09a8; x = 0x1c7a010; *x = abcdefghi; x_size = 9 
befor func2 x = 0x7fff78cb09a8; *x = 0x1c7a010; **x = abcdefghi; x_size = 9


after func2 x = 0x7fff78cb09a8; *x = 0x1c7a010; **x = zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih; x_size = 19
after func1 &x = 0x7fff78cb09a8; x = 0x1c7a010; *x = zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih; x_size = 19 
after  main &x = 0x7fff78cb09c8; x = 0x1c7a010; x = zyxwvutsrqponmlkjih; x_size = 19
```

The program still works after introducing multiple mallocs.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the correct [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format to print pointers (more specifically `void *`, a cast is needed) is `%p`. Mismatching format specifier and argument types (like using the `unsigned int` format `%u` to print a pointer) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It's probably sheer coincidence and luck that, together with the fact that your program has a really really simple memory layout, let it happens. Since you always free before mallocating again, malloc is able to return the same pointer over and over again. To verify this, you can probably 'break' the program by adding `char *y = malloc(10);` right after declaring x. Then, func2's malloc won't be able to use the same, 10 bytes long storage, for its larger buffer, and should return somewhere else... tho it's still implementation dependant. (Not an answer since not verified nor well written.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I forgot about the %p. Thanks for reminding. I was initially using `%02x`. But that was having only 1 character difference and confusing. So I went with %u.

Comment: @Alceste_ I tried your suggestion and updated the question with the findings.

Comment: Tbh I would still tend to stick to my explanation (which is well enhanced by some programmer dude's answer. Maybe your malloc implementation has a default space between buffers of more than 100 bytes, which would ease realloc optimisation. You can either break it by brk ing a smaller overall memory for you program or, much more easily, by using megabytes buffer as string. (while still using the few first if need be)

Answer (score 3):

What you have is *undefined behavior*.

Here follows the important parts of your program (with renamed variables to be able to differ between them in the functions):

```
void func2(char **x)
{
    free(*x);
    *x = malloc(SOME_OTHER_SIZE);
}

void func1(char *y)
{
    func2(&y);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *z = malloc(SOME_SIZE);
    func1(z);
}
```

In the `main` function you allocate some memory, and make `z` point to it.

Then you call `func1` passing the pointer `z` *by value*, meaning that the pointer is copied into the `func1` argument variable `y`. Now you have two pointers pointing to the same memory: `z` in the `main` function and `y` in the `func1` function.

Then `func1` calls `func2`, but it *emulates pass by reference* by passing not a copy of the value in `y` but a pointer to the variable `y` itself. When `func2` free's the memory pointed to by `*x`, it invalidates the pointers `*x`, `y` and `z`. It then reassigns `*x` to point to some new memory. This will change where `y` is pointing but not `z`, which will still be invalid.

When `func1` returns the pointer `z` is no longer valid, any attempt to dereference it will lead to said *undefined behavior*.

---

Somewhat graphically it could be seen like this:

1. The `main` function allocates memory and makes `z` point to it:

   ```
   +---+     +-----------+
   | z | --> | Memory... |
   +---+     +-----------+
   ```
2. The function `func1` is called, passing a copy of `z`:

   ```
   +---+
   | z | -\
   +---+   \    +-----------+
            >-> | Memory... |
   +---+   /    +-----------+
   | y | -/
   +---+
   ```
3. The function `func2` is called, passing a pointer to `y`:

   ```
             +---+
             | z | -\
             +---+   \    +-----------+
                      >-> | Memory... |
   +---+     +---+   /    +-----------+
   | x | --> | y | -/
   +---+     +---+
   ```
4. The function `func2` free's the memory pointed to by `*x`:

   ```
             +---+
             | z | -\
             +---+   \    
                      >-> ???
   +---+     +---+   /    
   | x | --> | y | -/
   +---+     +---+
   ```
5. The function `func2` allocates new memory and makes `*x` (and therefore `y`) point to it:

   ```
             +---+
             | z | --> ???
             +---+       

   +---+     +---+     +---------------+
   | x | --> | y | --> | New memory... |
   +---+     +---+     +---------------+
   ```

From the above it should hopefully be easy to see why `free(*x)` in `func2` will invalidate `z` from the `main` function as well.

Now the interesting part, which is why the memory pointed to by `z` in the `main` function seems to be changed: It's seems to be a quirk of the memory allocator in your system, where it maps the new allocation to the same location as the old allocation. The important point is that `z` is still invalid.

Answer (score -2):

You seem to think that using `char *x` (a single pointer) as an argument for `func1` was a mistake. However, I think it's perfectly fine. `func1` is expecting a pointer to char as an argument, or basically a memory address that when dereferenced gives a char or bunch of chars. When you write `func1(x);` in main, you are passing x, the address of a bunch of chars, which is just the type of argument `func1` was expecting.

Why is x the address of a bunch of chars?
In this case, the pointer `x` is storing the address of an array (of characters). Now, you might know that if you just write the name of an array, you get the base address of the array. See the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf ("%d\n", arr);       // address of the first element (1) of the array
                                // or, the base address of the array
    printf ("%d\n", &arr[0]);   // same as above
    printf ("%d\n\n", *arr);      // gives the first element of the array

    int *x = malloc (5*sizeof (int));
    *x = 1;
    *(x+1) = 2;
    *(x+2) = 3;
    *(x+3) = 4;
    *(x+4) = 5;
    printf ("%d\n", x);        // address of the first element (1) of the array
                               // or, the base address of the array
    printf ("%d\n", &*(x+0));  // same as above
    printf ("%d\n\n", *x);     // gives the first element of the array
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
6356712
6356712
1

9768168
9768168
1
```

Now, why are we able to modify the values in the character array pointed to by x? Because we have passed the base address of that array. We can dereference that address to get to the array and do whatever we want with it.

Comment: I don't see any relevance in this answer to the question.